# Hide cck field based on role

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Im looking for a way to hide a cck field for every one except for one specific role.

I know that there is a module, Content Permission module, that takes good care of this. But I have taken over a very big site with many content types, with lots of related cck fields being defined. So installing Content Permission module is not a good idea because of the great amount of settings it would require.

It's a drupal 6 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may use hook_nodeapi in a custom module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_nodeapi().
 */
function yourmodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
      if (! user_access('show restricted content')) {
        unset ($node->content['field_restrictedcontent']);
      }
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_perm().
 */
function yourmodule_perm () {
  return array(
    'show restricted content',
  );
}
```

Nevertheless, be aware that this is somewhat a hack: I think you should reconsider using Content Permission module for your site, and make the effort needed to configure it for your node types. It's a one time job and it may protect you from compatibilities issues with other modules in your site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use any of the permissions module and reconfigure each of those fields in question. With code, you have to check user roles for each of those fields!